# Setting Message Properties using Spring Cloud Stream with RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I want to make use of the [Validated User-ID](https://www.rabbitmq.com/validated-user-id.html) functionality offered by RabbitMQ to securely identify the sender of an event. When I use the RabbitTemplate directly this is easily achieved as follows

```
template.convertAndSend("exchange.name", "route.key", message, m -> {
     m.getMessageProperties().setUserId("user-name");
     return m;
});
```

The above works, however when I try to replicate this in a project with Spring Cloud Stream there isn't a "place" to set the properties and setting the field as a header doesn't work. Is there a workaround or a better way to achieve this? Am I missing something obvious please?

Comment: Did you try setting user id header on `Message`? For example, from Rabbit dashboard you can specify message properties/headers

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky Setting the user id header doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RabbitMQ Binder producer is fully based on Spring Integration's `AmqpOutboundEndpoint` which, in turn, uses a `DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper`, where there is a logic like this in the `populateStandardHeaders` :

```
.acceptIfNotNull(getHeaderIfAvailable(headers, AmqpHeaders.USER_ID, String.class),
                    amqpMessageProperties::setUserId);
```

So, if you set a `amqp_userId` header into a message you try to producer, it must be mapped to the mention `userId` AMQP message property.

Comment: My problem seemed to have been not using the exact header name as I was using user-id. Using `AmqpHeaders.USER_ID` which translates to `amqp_userId` as you correctly indicated solved my problem thanks. For anyone reading this, on the receiving end the header is `amqp_receivedUserId`